# Unit Test Adapter threw exception: URI formats are not supported

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, unit-testing, mstest

In Visual Studio 2010 when I create the default test project with the following bare bones code:

```vb
<TestClass()>
Public Class UnitTest1

    <TestMethod()>
    Public Sub TestMethod1()

        Assert.AreEqual(1, 1)

    End Sub

End Class
```

I get the following error:

> Unit Test Adapter threw exception:
>   URI formats are not supported..
>   -- Exception doesn't have a stack trace --

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Open up **`Local.testsettings`** in your Solution Explorer > Solution Items
   [image: local.testSettings]
2. Go to Deployment and make sure **`Enabled Deployment`** is checked 
   <sup>(it's unchecked by default)</sup>
   [image: Enabled Deployment]