# Unit Test Adapter threw exception: URI formats are not supported.. error when doing coded ui test

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, coded-ui-tests

I've started trying out coded ui tests in visual-studio-2010 and I get the following error: 
"Unit Test Adapter threw exception: 
URI formats are not supported.."

I've tried searching for answers but I'm not really sure where to put the fix. When I recorded the test, visual studio recognized the calculator source as "%SystemRoot%\System32\calc.exe" could that be the problem? Or is the problem to do with a setting in one of the project files?

Right now I'm just doing a trial test using calculator in windows, eventually I want to do the test on a web site.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dug around a bit more and I found that if you open the 'local.testsettings' file in visual studio and mark the checkbox 'enable deployment' under 'deployment' that fixes the problem.

See other post about the error: [Link to question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509543/unit-test-adapter-threw-exception-uri-formats-are-not-supported)